# Periodical sum of rows by a certain step

Tags: matrix, summation, row

I've been struggling with one problem. I have a classic matrix in this example 12x4 such as:
`matrix = Table[i, {i, 12}, {4}]`

`TableForm@matrix`

I need to sum the rows according to the example below.

`Total@matrix[[{1, 5, 9}]]`

`Total@matrix[[{2, 6, 10}]]`

`Total@matrix[[{3, 7, 11}]`

I tried using MapAt, but without any real success so far.
I need to make a function out of it, cause later I will be using it for matrix 1036x37.
Any tips?

Comment: Why not contain {4,8,12}?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) to create a "summing" matrix, and use [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot):

```
SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, Band[{1, 5}] -> 1, Band[{1, 9}] -> 1}, {3, 12}] . matrix
```

> {{15, 15, 15, 15}, {18, 18, 18, 18}, {21, 21, 21, 21}}

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[f1]
f1[m_] :=  Total[Transpose @ Partition[m, Dimensions[m][[2]]], {2}]

f1 @ matrix
```

> ```
> {15, 15, 15, 15}, {18, 18, 18, 18}, {21, 21, 21, 21}, {24, 24, 24, 24}}}
> ```

Inspired by Carl's answer, an alternative way to use `Dot`:

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2[m_] :=  Module[{d = Dimensions @ m}, 
  PadRight[IdentityMatrix[Last @ d], Reverse @ d, "Periodic"].m]

f2@matrix
```

> ```
> {{15, 15, 15, 15}, {18, 18, 18, 18}, {21, 21, 21, 21}, {24, 24, 24, 24}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

sum[matrix_?MatrixQ, start_Integer?Positive, step_Integer?Positive] :=
  Total@matrix[[start ;; ;; step]]

matrix = Table[i, {i, 12}, {4}];

sum[matrix, 1, 4]

(* {15, 15, 15, 15} *)

sum[matrix, 2, 4]

(* {18, 18, 18, 18} *)

sum[matrix, 3, 4]

(* {21, 21, 21, 21} *)
```

Or

```
sum[matrix, #, 4] & /@ Range[3]

(* {{15, 15, 15, 15}, {18, 18, 18, 18}, {21, 21, 21, 21}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we set n=14 instead of n=12 to test the method.

```
n = 14;
matrix = Table[i, {i, n}, {4}];
d = 4;
m = 3;
index = Table[i + d (j - 1), {i, n + d - d*m}, {j, m}]
Total[matrix[[#]]] & /@ index
```

> `{{1, 5, 9}, {2, 6, 10}, {3, 7, 11}, {4, 8, 12}, {5, 9, 13}, {6, 10,  14}}`

> `{{15, 15, 15, 15}, {18, 18, 18, 18}, {21, 21, 21, 21}, {24, 24, 24,  24}, {27, 27, 27, 27}, {30, 30, 30, 30}}`

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following code:

```
RowsSum[nmax_Integer?Positive, length_Integer?Positive, vector_List] := Module[
   {matrix, matrixrows, s},
matrix = Table[i, {i, nmax}, {length}]; 
matrixrows[vector2_List, matrix_] := matrix[[vector]]; 
s = Flatten@Map[Total, List[matrixrows[vector, matrix]]];
Return[s];
];
```

Test:

```
RowsSum[12, 4, {1, 5, 9}]
(*{15, 15, 15, 15}*)
RowsSum[12, 4, {2, 6, 10}]
(*{18, 18, 18, 18}*)
RowsSum[12, 4, {3, 7, 11}]
(*{21, 21, 21, 21}*)
```

With conditions:

```
RowsSum[nmax_Integer?Positive, length_Integer?Positive,condition_] := Module[
{matrix, vector, matrixrows, s},
matrix = Table[i, {i, nmax}, {length}]; 
vector = Select[Table[i, {i, Length[matrix]}], condition]; 
matrixrows[vector2_List, matrix_] := matrix[[vector]]; 
s = Flatten@Map[Total, List[matrixrows[vector, matrix]]];
Return[s];
];
```

Test:

```
RowsSum[12, 4, OddQ]
(*{36, 36, 36, 36}*)
RowsSum[12, 4, EvenQ]
(*{42, 42, 42, 42}*)
RowsSum[12, 4, 5 < # < 10 &]
(*{30, 30, 30, 30}*)
```